# Extra space below rows that appears when scrolling to the bottom of a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Ok, so I have a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) (the standard WPF [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx), which comes with .Net 4.0, NOT the WPF Toolkit DataGrid) with the CanUserAddRows=false.  It's bound to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel.  It has a MaxHeight set properly, so that it will scroll if there are too many rows for the screen.

It works just fine the way it is, except for the fact that if the user puts their mouse over the DataGrid and then moves the Scroll-wheel downwards, then some extra space appears below the rows:

[image: Strange DataGrid]

**I would rather that the gray space does not appear in this case (where there is no need to scroll).  How do I accomplish this?**

P.S. I've actually built my own functionality for a new row at the bottom of the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) due to some special requirements for our program, thus the blank row at the bottom of the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx). It's done totally in the VM, so it shouldn't affect the answer to this question.

### Update:

This behavior happens on every [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) I have currently.  However, when the MaxHeight is set on the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx), and there are more rows than can be displayed, then the content starts to scroll.  In this situation, the grey space below the lines is variable in size.  That is, since the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) scrolls based on content rather than physical scrolling (see [this for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll.aspx) about the difference, under the remarks section), there is a little extra space at the bottom below the last row when you scroll all the way to the bottom.  The grey space fills that extra space.  Here is an example:

[image: Strange DataGrid Behavior 2]

To clarify, I don't mind that behavior that much, it's just when the grey space appears when there is no need for scrolling.  I just thought that this behavior would help indicate the cause of the problem.

### Update #2:

I have discovered what can cause the problem: if you set the EnableRowVirtualization to false, then this problem occurs.  **However, if I want to set it to false, how can I prevent the grey space/"extra line" from occurring when there is no need to scroll?** (this is my main concern and the main point of this question)

Comment: It actually happens on my machine at home, but not on my machine at work. Happy that I am not the only one seeing this?

Comment: Huh.  I have noticed that it is a little fickle... Though I can usually get it to happen eventually.  Not exactly sure what it depends on...

Comment: What if you try to set the datagrid to read only. Is it then still happening?

Comment: Hmm... after a quick test- yes it still happens when I set the IsReadOnly="True" for the DataGrid.  What does that mean in this case?  I can still edit the DataGrid when I set that property.

Comment: I'd try creating a simple `List` and assigning it to `ItemsSource`. Just to make totaly sure this has nothing to do with the ViewModel and its modifications (perhaps, asynchrony and other stuff).

Comment: BTW, could you clarify your main concern: 1) do you want to remove the extera row, or 2) do you want the grid scrolling stop when the last element just enters the visible area at its bottom, or 3) do you want the grid to take as little space as possible while there's no need in scrolling?

Comment: @PavelGatilov: I have added an update to my question above and tried to clarify my main concern.  I want to remove the extra "row"- the empty gray space.  I find it distracting to the user, and it takes up useful space.

Answer (score 5):

I've faced the same issue. In my case extra space at the bottom was because MaxHeight being set and bacause of

```
VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
```

After setting it to

```
VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
```

the problem actually dissapears (still having MaxHeight property)

Answer (score 3):

Try this: Set

- `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` to `False`
- `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled`

Then

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid"
          RowHeaderWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=RowHeight}"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You question is a little unclear but I can offer some investigative steps to find out what the cause is.

1. Make sure that your observable collection is not harboring any null values. A null entry in the collection will still show up in the grid as a blank row.
2. The fact that it is happening on different environment means that your data source may be different, so that is a good place to check. Check here that the count of the collection is directly matched with the number of rows on the grid (including the empty row).
3. Make sure that this is not a control templating issue. If possible, look at the `Style` and `DataTemplate` for your `DataGrid` control to see if this is not a visual side-effect.

Apart from that, you should include more details in your question, such as the type of `DataGrid` you are using (eg. WPF Toolkit, Telerik, DevExpress, etc) so that we can rule out a templating issue.

Comment: I have clarified the question, including some details about the DataGrid I'm using at the beginning.  I'm using the WPF .Net 4 DataGrid (not the WPF Toolkit DataGrid, which I understand is slightly different).  There are clearly no null values in the observable collection.  The count of the collection is directly matched with the number of rows (NOT INCLUDING the grey space, which I'm not convinced is an empty row).  And the DataTemplate is the standard one from Microsoft- there isn't anything obvious that is wrong.  Hope that helps.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was caused by the `DataGrid`'s `MaxHeight` property not being set to a multiple of the row size, so the left over space was showing up at the bottom of the `DataGrid`. For example: if there are 5 rows that are 10 pixels in height and the `MaxHeight` property is set to 55 then there will be 5 pixels of space at the bottom.

Comment: Actually: [ dataGridMaxHeight - headerRowHeight % rowHeight == 0 ]. This should be the accepted answer. Solution is actually quite simple, but your post helped me a lot, thanks.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. There is too much of unused space in the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I guess it may be because that DataGrid has to show the first *visible* row at row boundary, e.g. it can't display only the lower half of the first visible row in order to make the last row align with the bottom of the control.

You can test that by two steps:
1) scroll to the bottom of your DataGrid, and see the extra gray space;
2) slowly resize the DataGrid (or its containing window) vertically, and see how that gray space change, while noting the first visible row stays unmoved.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and the answer is simple.
All you have to do is to put the following in your datagrid definition in XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"
CanUserAddRows="false"
```

and you are clear.

Another similar stuff is, if you get a blank column in your data grid then the solution is to put the Width="*" in your last column definition also in XAML.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: -1: the author have clearly pointed out that he/she already has `CanUserAddRows="false"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Set ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" & ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" in DataGrid.
```

Answer (score -1):

set both `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` and `CanUserAddRows` to `false`.